# Python Pandas - Set multiple variable types based on column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have labeled my dataset columns systematically where the suffix of categorical variables have "_c" at the end and numeric fields have "_n".

I would like python pandas code that will set the variable types based on the naming of the column headers.  So for all "_c" variables I need to set them to "category" and all "_n" variables set them to "float" or "int".

Here is sample data:

| fav_color_c | fav_food_c | income_n | height_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | pizza | 100 | 68 |
| blue | chicken | 200 | 70 |
| green | bbq | 300 | 64 |

Can set variable types individually but having trouble to do this for a large list of variables.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any ideas you came up with yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col.endswith('_c'):
        df[col]=df[col].astype(str)
    if col.endswith('_n'):
        df[col]=df[col].astype(int)
df
```